# maven-javadoc-plugin - target directory for jar file

Tags: java, maven, maven-javadoc-plugin

Is there a way to specify the output directory for the generated jar for `maven-javadoc-plugin`? (Clarification: say to a subdirectory of the default `target` folder.)

This is with reference to the generated `jar` file. Not the output directory of the generated javadoc html files (specified by the `<outputDirectory>` parameter).

Have seen references to the `maven-assembly-plugin` on some similar posts. IMHO, seems like to have to take a pretty long winded approach to use `maven-assembly-plugin` just to have the javadoc jar generated in a different folder?

Comment: What do you need a target directory because the it's using the default `target` directory..

Comment: Looking to put the javadoc jar in a subdirectory of the `target` folder since in our existing setup other tasks already sweep up files from the `target` root (and don't want javadoc jar to be picked up). In this scenario, just having the javadoc jar in a specific subdirectory (that is filtered) would do the job with minimal impact.

I've adding a clarification to my question for clarity.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you real problem is... The javadoc plugin generates the resulting jar file (xyz-1.0-javadoc.jar) in `target` directory... the other side of the coin is that it's downloaded from your ide... Can you please describe in detail what kind of problem you have? Why is it needed to make a separate directory in target ?

Comment: If only the `maven-javadoc-plugin` could be configured to produce the generated jar in say `target/subdirectory/xyz-1.0.0-javadoc.jar` that would do the job. The default location (`target/xyz-1.0.0-javadoc.jar`) is not desirable in our current situation as the files  from target root get copied to different places i.e. into container images etc.  Several operations are done as part of a Jenkins build on our build server (at the end the deploy phase would push the artifacts to a Nexus server). javadoc jar is not required to be included in all generated artifacts.

Comment: Why is that neccesary ? The foundation of Maven is "Convention over configuration" paradigm... and I recommend not to change that or use profiles for such thing... just keep it as it...

Comment: No denying that. Sometimes its hard to explain these best practice principles to the powers that be and we have to balance it with a bit of give and take!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Maven you can define the output directory for `javadoc:jar` directly. You could try to give it a specific value for `jarOutputDirectory` in the config for the execution of javadoc goal:
`<jarOutputDirectory>target/docfoldername</jarOutputDirectory>`

Alternatively you could also use a different profile in maven where you call  the `javadoc:jar` specifically, as it might be easier depending on the requirements.
Perhaps for instance:

```
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-javadoc-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jarOutputDirectory>Target/docs</jarOutputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```